# Batch script to download and save XLS file to directory

Tags: php, url, batch-file, xls

I am trying to write some batch script to download and save an XLS file from a URL. I am able to down load the file by using

@ECHO OFF
start /d "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE url link
exit

I would now like to save these files to a folder or directory.

Any help anyone could provide here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you're using Windows, does this answer help?

[http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget](http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget)

Comment: I am using windows. Thank you for your response, unfortunately the link above does not seem to work.

Comment: What has this got to do with PHP?

Comment: Here's the link again: http://superuser.com/questions/25538/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-wget

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do it.

1. Like [Buddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715829/buddy) suggested, use a command-line downloader, for example [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).
2. Under Linux, you can run PHP directly (even without a webserver). See [PHP: Command Line PHP on Microsoft Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php) in PHP manual.

Don't run a browser, or - even worse - IE, just to run a PHP script.